# Bootstrap 4 collapse changes width of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was working with bootstrap and found out a weird issue. When using collapse button, page width is changed (changes to lower), when I press collapse again to hide the shown content, page is reset to normal. What can be causing the issue?

```
<a class="btn btn-icon btn-light" data-toggle="collapse" href="#article-content1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="article-content1">
    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="article-content1">
  <div class="card-body">
    You can show or hide this card.
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
          <img alt="image" src="./assets/img/avatar/avatar.png" class="rounded-circle avatar-outline ml-autox" alt="" width="46" height="46" style="margin-top:-3px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-left">
          <strong>Jasmine Snow</strong></br>
          <span class="color-muted">November 11, 2020</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5"><!-- empty --></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By how much is it changing? I have seen this happening when there is a long content inside the collapse which causes the scrollbar to appear when opening it.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal turns out that was the issue indeed.

Comment: Glad to help, these things can be tricky to debug unless you've burnt your hands once. If you are forced to solve it, try slim-scroll may be.